# Can't understand cron-job time

Tags: linux, cron

I have something like this `0,30 * * * * /some/command`, I am not sure, is this executed every 30 minutes ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the command would be executed every 30 minutes.

```
0,30      <---------------    execute at 0 minutes and 30 minutes into the hour. 
*         <---------------    every hour in the day
*         <---------------    every day of the month
*         <---------------    every month
*         <---------------    every day of the week
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron